# AtmelStudio 7 installation failed for avr8 device support package

Tags: installation, avr, atmel, atmelstudio

I am trying to install AtmelStudio 7 on Windows 7, but the installation stopped after some time. The following error message is shown:

> An error occured
>   AVR8 Device Support

[image]

What i tried so far:

- I took also a quick look at [Atmel-FAQ](http://atmel.force.com/support/articles/en_US/FAQ/Atmel-Studio-Installer-Questions), but the suggested solution (call `as-installer-*.exe SHELLCOMMAND=/NoWeb /NoRefresh /NoRestart`) did result in the same error message.
- I scanned the log messages, but failed to find something helpful.
- Remove all Atmel components and drivers by using the Windows uninstall mechanism

**Question**

Has anybody an idea how to get AtmelStudio 7 installed?

**Update**

I solved the installation problem as follows:

The error indicated that the IDE installation is corrupt chances are the registry keys are messed up.

1) Go to a command prompt and run the following command

```
wmic product where "vendor like 'Atmel%'" get Name, Version
```

This will list the product which are part of the machine and comes from Atmel. If it lists either 'Atmel Studio IDE 7.0' or 'Atmel Studio Development Environment' chances are component is not uninstalled properly.

2) In order to clean up the above component use a third party utility(http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to remove the above components from the system.

Note: In order for Revo Uninstaller to list the above components go to Tools->Options->Show System components and check it.

3) After the clean up of the above component and registry to verify the clean up succeeded run the following command again.

```
wmic product where "vendor like 'Atmel%'" get Name, Version
```

If the clean up was successful it should not list 'Atmel Studio IDE 7.0' or 'Atmel Studio Development Environment'.

4) Now you can install Atmel Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the error after having uninstalled Atmel Studio 7.0.582.
Unfortunately, it messed up the registry, such that I could not use the "wmic" program (it just does not anything for an eternity).
After some hours of searching, I found this Microsoft tool for fixing install/uninstall issues:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed

Using that is easy and the steps described above very similar:

- Choose "Problems with uninstalling" (or something like that)
- Find and select either 'Atmel Studio IDE 7.0' or 'Atmel Studio Development Environment'
- Apply the corrections

After that, I was able to install AS 7.0.1006 sucessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have the same failure on a laptop running win7
When I checked the log files found the following error, but I still have not been able to fix it...

```
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SOURCEDIR = C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C327F1B0-01E9-45BB-AE07-AD204C992A31}v7.0.922\
Property(S): SourcedirProduct = {C327F1B0-01E9-45BB-AE07-AD204C992A31}
Property(S): ProductToBeRegistered = 1
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:248]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:249]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:249]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT Message FROM Error WHERE Error = 1708 
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:249]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:249]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT Message FROM Error WHERE Error = 1709 
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:249]: Product: AVR8 Device Support — Installation failed.
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:250]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: AVR8 Device Support. Product Version: 7.0.922. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Atmel. Installation success or error status: 1603.
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:255]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (58:48) [13:08:41:255]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (58:D4) [13:08:41:259]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (58:D4) [13:08:41:259]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
=== Logging stopped: 7/3/2016  13:08:41 ===
MSI (s) (58:D4) [13:08:41:264]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (58:D4) [13:08:41:264]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (58:D4) [13:08:41:264]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (58:D4) [13:08:41:267]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (58:D4) [13:08:41:268]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (s) (58:D4) [13:08:41:269]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (58:50) [13:08:41:269]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (FC:64) [13:08:41:282]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (FC:64) [13:08:41:283]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 7/3/2016  13:08:41 ===</code><br/>
```

Maybe these resources helps you.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834484
http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/1922756#comment-1922756
**If anybody knows what's going wrong, please let us konw !**
Thanks !

Comment: I added additional information on how i solved the issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue that happened to me is hanging the installation at
*Atmel Studio Development Environment Applying

Details: Initializing environment*
And the useful solution is killing the AtmelStudio.exe (*32) process which was apparently running in the background as part of the installation process.
The following link is where I found the solution:
http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/1918991#comment-1918991

And finally after some seemingly scary steps...!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]